# Realtime update is returning only the changed document not the whole query

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore real time  update, I have the following listener

```
 CollectionReference collecRef = db.collection("lists").document("doc1").collection("locations");
changesListener=collecRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                return;
            }
            a
            for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) 
            {
                DocumentSnapshot document = dc.getDocument();
             // this is where I expected to loop over all documents. But instead it is only one item..the changed the document

            }

        }
    });
```

According to docs:

> It is often useful to see the actual changes to query results between
>   query snapshots, instead of simply using the entire query snapshot.

This implies that when a document is modified then I am expecting the whole query to rerun since there is a change to the results. However, in the listener  I only get a documentsnapshot of the document that has been changed not all whole query results (ie all the documents in my case)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The code you shared does nothing with the `QuerySnapshot`. Can you share the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: This is the code of the listener where it gets called upon changes. First time it gets called, it gets me 21 documents with details. Then when a change happens to one of the documents, this only gets me one document... the one being changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `snapshots.getDocumentChanges()` you get only the documents that were changed. If you want to get all documents, call [`QuerySnapshot.getDocuments()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#getDocuments()).

```
for (Document document : snapshots.getDocuments()) {
    ... do something with document ...
```